# Problem with installing pygame through Pycharm and CMD

Tags: python, pygame

I have problem with installing pygame, when I'm trying to do this in PyCharm by "File -> Project Settings -> Project Interpreter" I'm getting this error:

```
Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x86"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\voko\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
        buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
      File "C:\Users\voko\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
        deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
      File "C:\Users\voko\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
        and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
      File "C:\Users\voko\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
        reply = raw_input(
    EOFError: EOF when reading a line

    ----------------------------------------

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\voko\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\
```

By CMD attempt it says:

[image]